# Freezing Cold Brew?

Tags: storage, cold-brew

Folks established in [this question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/1633/6835)* that freezing hot-brewed coffee isn't a great idea.  But what about cold brewed coffee concentrate?  Given that cold brew is already at fridge temperature, it seems like I ought to be able to freeze it without changing it much.

If I can freeze it, what steps should I take to preserve flavor through freezing and thawing, and why?  If I can't freeze it, why not?  What happens?

Comment: (* there is one answer to that question about cold brew, but it's not upvoted and contradicts other answers, so I wanted to ask a question specifically about freezing cold brew)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can freeze cold brew. There was a time in my life when I did exactly that. I prepared cold brew in a large batch, then, each day before work, I filled a stainless steel water bottle and stuck that in the freezer overnight. Next day, the bottle would go straight to the fridge at work in the morning, and by lunchtime I'd have drinkable, iced cold brew. Worked great. I did this for about two years and never had an issue.

You don't need to take any unusual steps. Use a fully enclosed container to prevent sublimation of water (ice). Any kind of bottle or jar that can safely handle liquid expansion during freezing is fine.